# Test cases failing for jersey client

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have jersey client like

```
 public ClientResponse getCall(String apiName){
         restClient = getRestClient();
        WebResource webResource = restClient
                .resource(Constants.FUELWISE_END_POINT+apiName);
         return  webResource.accept(Constants.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .header(Constants.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, Constants.AUTHORIZATION_VALUE).get(ClientResponse.class);
    }
```

and have mockito test case line like:

```
   @Test
    public void getCallTest() {

        when(restClient.resource(any(String.class))).thenReturn(webResource);

        when(webResource.accept(any(String.class)).header(any(String.class), any(Object.class))
                .get(eq(ClientResponse.class))).thenReturn(clientResponse);

        restUtilityTest.getCall("messages");
    }
```

have extened test java class to return restClient mock  instead of Client.create()  from method getRestClient()

using Annotations for mocking using @Mock

Stack trace error :

```
This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
```

Mocking done in test case file  :

```
    @InjectMocks
    private RestUtilityTest restUtilityTest;

    @Mock
    private Client restClient;

    @Mock
    private WebResource webResource;

    @Mock(name = "response")
    private ClientResponse clientResponse;
```

Comment: There's not enough context to help.  Please update the question with additional code (and format the code).

Comment: Get rest client Code  :

Comment: @divyanayan you should really [edit] this additional information into the question. Not in the comments section.

Comment: @divyanayan show how the subject under test is initialized and how the mocked dependencies are injected.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the subject under test and its dependencies are arranged correctly.

```
@Test
public void getCallTest() {
    //Arrange    
    ClientResponse clientResponse = mock(ClientResponse.class);

    WebResource webResource = mock(WebResource.class);    
    when(webResource
            .accept(any(String.class))
            .header(any(String.class), any(String.class))
            .get(eq(ClientResponse.class))
        )
        .thenReturn(clientResponse);

    Client restClient = mock(Client.class);
    when(restClient.resource(any(String.class))).thenReturn(webResource);

    RestUtilityTest restUtilityTest = new RestUtilityTest(restClient);

    //Act
    ClientResponse response = restUtilityTest.getCall("messages");

    //Assert
    //...
}
```

Note the use of `any(String.class)` and `eq()` to match arguments

The above assumes that the mocked web resource is being properly injected into the subject class under test.

Comment: Tried the approach mentioned with eq()  but getting null pointer again.Yes i have mocked all the necessary components.

Comment: @divyanayan then you need to show that in the question so we can better help you. Without enough context there is not much else we can do bu guess.

Comment: @divyanayan formatting is done in the question. edit it into the original question

Comment: Updated please check